# angularJS send parameter from template to controller

Tags: angularjs

I want to do something like this

```
<div ng-controller="test" init="category = 1">
...
</div>
```

and in my controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('test', ['$scope, $http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/categories' + $scope.category...
}]);
```

but it doesn´t work like that. any ideas on how to pass a parameter from the template to the controller definition? thank you.

Comment: why you want to pass through HTML, If you can directly pass from the controller?

Comment: because I´m using angularJS with PHP and the I´m using the same angularJS controller in multiple pages. I need a way to pass a parameter from PHP to the angularJS controller to make the appropriate $http call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, hope it'll solve your problem.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div ng-controller="test" init="init(1)">
```

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('test', ['$scope, $http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function (category) {
        $http.get('/categories' + category);
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The directive is called `ngInit`, so to use it correctly you'd do it like this:

```
<div ng-controller="test" ng-init="category = 1">
...
</div>
```

Using `ngInit` for initialization can be considered an anti-pattern [according to the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit), except for certain specific use cases. You mention passing data from PHP to Angular, which is an acceptable use case, but I would probably consider a different solution to avoid `ngInit`:

```
<script>
    angular.module('myApp').constant('MY_DATA', {
        category: 1
    });
</script>
```

You just add this to your PHP page somewhere after you load in your angular application. Then you can inject `MY_DATA` into your controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('test', ['MY_DATA', function (MY_DATA) {
    $http.get('/categories' + MY_DATA.category);
}]);
```

Comment: It's particularly useful if you're initializing multiple values from server side scripting, since initializing multiple values through `ngInit` quickly becomes difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
<div ng-controller="test" init="init(1)"></div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.category = 0;

$scope.init = function(myCategory){ 
   $scope.category = myCategory;
   $scope.callGetFunction(); //$http.get('/categories' + $scope.category...
}
```